# Why is liquid include statement in Tag markup rather than Output markup

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I've been playing with jekyll, which uses liquid, and I've noticed that include staments are in tag markup `{% include foo.html %}` instead of output markup `{{ include foo.html }}`.

The description of tag vs output markup on the  [liquid wiki](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers)
just says that output markup resolves to text, while tag markup is for logic.  It seems to me that `include` resolves to text so why isn't it in double curly brackets?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, {% include foo.html %} does eventually resolve to text, but it doesn't necessarily have to. You might use {% include twitter.svg %} as the default footer for Jekyll does. This resolves to an image rather than text.